# MVC Bool properties into single string property

Tags: .net, model-view-controller

I have class that consists of 10 bool properties. My viewmodel has single string property. I am trying to map bool values into this string property in controller. Is it possible? Also, is it possible to return column names of table which consists of bool properties, to avoid true false values in view.

Answer (score 0):

First part: Yes, just concatenate all properties together and convert bool to string on each one as you do so.  I won't elaborate as I must admit I don't see a good use case for this.  Happy to explain in more detail if above doesn't make sense and you can explain a use case for this.  Second part: Yes - either use a view model that returns Yes/No strings instead of booleans or use helper methods or partial class to do something like

```
class myClass 
{
    public bool prop1 {get; set;}
    public bool prop2 {get; set;}
    public bool prop3 {get; set;}
    //etc

    public string prop1String { get { return prop1 ? "Yes" : "No"} }
    public string prop2String { get { return prop2 ? "Yes" : "No"} }
    public string prop3String { get { return prop3 ? "Yes" : "No"} }
    //etc
}
```

Just call the alternative properties (prop1String, etc) to display Yes, No fields instead of true, false.